# How to use bootstrap in my back-end module?

Tags: magento2, header

I'm trying to build my first backend module and I was wondering if it is possible to use the bootstrap in the Magento Backend, or if it is only with html tags? I tried to use the bootstrap added in the `default_head_blocks.xml` of my module but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show some code so that someone can assist better.  Saying _it didn't' work_ doesn't guide anyone to where or *why* you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing there was no information to go on from the question, so I am answering based on some assumptions - until the question is broadly improved where someone else may assist further.

The Magento 2 `default_head_blocks.xml` generally only goes into your **theme folder, not in the *code folder of a module***.   **This is also only for the *frontend* area.**

In other words for frontend, do not put it in `app/code/Vendor/Theme/` folder, but it needs to be registered as a **Theme**.

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

However since you are targeting an `adminhtml`, the file `default_head_blocks.xml` are not used as far as I can see.

You could potentially override any of these layout areas, and target `<head>` section as you wanted to with `default_head_blocks.xml`.
[Magento_Backend layouts](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/layout)

You should also take a look at [reference on how to add javascript resource using require-js](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html)

A possible way to do it:

```
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml:

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header">
            <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\YourBlock" template="VendorName_ModuleName::import-js.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates/import-js.phtml:

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        ['bootstrap'],
        function($) {
            $(function() {
                // My js code
            });
        });
</script>
```

See the references above on which folder locations will help you.